# Telegram posts to Wordpress posts

Tags: wordpress, telegram, telegram-bot

How can i send my telegram posts to wordpress?

is it possible for a telegram bot to post content to wordpress?
or is it possible to crawl telegram posts and copy them into wordpress?

Comment: A solution is to directly retrieve your posts using the [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/methods#working-with-messages)

Comment: @mohammad-mahdi-kouchakyazdi — Did you find a reasonable solution for this?

Comment: Check this tutorial https://valvepress.com/how-to-import-from-telegram-to-wordpress-posts-automatically/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These 5 Plugins is related to Telegram API regarding bots and notification and posting from WordPress to telegram channels

[Here's the Top 5 Plugins](https://www.wpsolver.com/wordpress-plugins-telegram/)

but if you look into posting telegram channel posts automatically in WordPress there is a Persian company that claims developed such a plugin Named [**WpProto**](https://faranevis.com/post/10/%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%B2%D9%88%D9%86%D9%87-WPProto-[-%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%84-%D9%BE%D8%B3%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%84-%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%AA%D9%84%DA%AF%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%A8%D9%87-%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%AF%D9%BE%D8%B1%D8%B3])

Comment: is there any other plugin for telegram to wordpress ?

Comment: @KouchakYazdi no other plugins as I know but do your own research and inform us if you find something. mamnon

Comment: check this tutorial https://valvepress.com/how-to-import-from-telegram-to-wordpress-posts-automatically/